# How do I make input elements "visible" to my script in newly appended rows?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a table that is loaded with data on page load. The user then can add more records if needed.

[image: screen_shot]

The append/remove function works as expected. My issue is that my script does not "see" the input elements on the newly appended rows. It works as expected on the rows generated on the page load.

Here is how I append the new rows:

```
  $('[name="add_charge"]').on( "click", function() { //add new rows for medications and costs     
  markup = "<tr id='tot_row'><td><input type='text' name='md_gpi'/></input></td><td>$<input 
  type='text' name='drug_price' class='price'/></input><td class='remove_charge'>-Remove</td></tr>";
  $('[name="med_charges"]').append(markup);
  });
```

This is how I iterate through the table to get values for insert.

```
function submit_drugs() {
    //insert all drugs          
var eff_date = $('[name="effective_date"]').val();
             $("#tot_row").each(function () {
                var gpi =  $(this).find('[name="md_gpi"]').val(); //<< does not find this
                var cost =  $(this).find('[name="drug_price"]').val();//<< does not find this
                    if ($.isNumeric(cost)){                              
                                        $.ajax({
                                            type: 'POST',
                                            url: 'data_page.php',
                                            data: 'dPatient='+patient+"&dGpi="+gpi+"&dCost="+cost+"&dDate="+eff_date,
                                            success: function(html) {                                            
                                                  console.log(html);        
                                            }
                                        });             
                    console.log(patient+"-"+gpi +"-"+cost+"-"+eff_date); 
                    }else {
                          //do something else 
                                    }
            })  

}
```

It is like I need to 'refresh' the dom or something. I just can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: ids are SINGULAR, you can not duplicate them. That is your issue. Use a class.

Comment: I had it as a class before. No dice.

Comment: `"#tot_row"` <-- that is the id look up that is not going to find the dupes

Comment: @epascarello - I changed it back and now it is working as expected. I have no idea why it didn't work before. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ids can not be duplicated when you look them up. Basic example below showing the problem.

```js
console.log('id:', $('#tot_row').length)
console.log('class', $('.tot_row').length)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id='tot_row' class='tot_row'></tr>
  <tr id='tot_row' class='tot_row'></tr>
  <tr id='tot_row' class='tot_row'></tr>
</table>
```

So alter the id to a class and change the selector to be a class.